# Form Cannot Find Action With IFormFile

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I can upload file on my local machine successfully but when i try to upload on host it can't find the action. I don't know why. Here's my code.

HTML

```
<form method="post" asp-action="UploadFile" asp-controller="Admin" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div class="custom-file">
        <input type="file" class="custom-file-input" id="file" name="file">
        <label class="custom-file-label" for="file">Browse</label>
    </div>
    <button class="btn btn-brand" type="submit">Upload</button>
</form>
```

C#

```
public IActionResult UploadFile([FromForm]IFormFile file)
    {
        var path = Path.Combine(_environment.WebRootPath, "uploads");
        if (file!= null && file.Length > 0)
        {
            using (var reader = new FileStream(Path.Combine(path, "gallery", file.FileName), FileMode.Create))
            {
                file.CopyTo(reader);
            }
            Gallery gallery = new Gallery
            {
                Path = file.FileName
            };

            db.Gallery.Add(gallery);
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
        return RedirectToAction("Gallery");
    }
```

Comment: Are you using Ajax or MVC form submit approach?

Comment: @TanvirArjel I'm using MVC.